# Codemirror keymap vim <Esc> not working

Tags: javascript, vim, codemirror, keymapping

I am using CodeMirror editor in my project. I used both the `/addon/display/fullscreen.js` and `/keymap/vim.js` scripts together and declared the CodeMirror instance like this,

```
var editor = CodeMirror.fromTextArea(document.getElementById("code"), {
  keyMap: "vim",
  extraKeys: {
    "F11": function(cm) {
      cm.setOption("fullScreen", !cm.getOption("fullScreen"));
    },
    "Esc": function(cm) {
      if (cm.getOption("fullScreen")) cm.setOption("fullScreen", false);
    }
  }
});
```

As shown, I have mapped the "Esc" key to exit the full screen display. Now, this key-mapping is overriding the "Esc" key-mapping defined in the `/keymap/vim.js` script for changing mode from `insert` to `visual`.

I checked the script and found this function,

```
function handleEsc() {
  if (key == '<Esc>') {
    // Clear input state and get back to normal mode.
    clearInputState(cm);
    if (vim.visualMode) {
      exitVisualMode(cm);
    } else if (vim.insertMode) {
      exitInsertMode(cm);
    }
    return true;
  }
}
```

Now, I think that I have to modify my declaration to something like this,

```
extraKeys: {
        "F11": function(cm) {
          cm.setOption("fullScreen", !cm.getOption("fullScreen"));
        },
        "Esc": function(cm) {
          if (cm.getOption("fullScreen")) cm.setOption("fullScreen", false);
          if (cm.getOption("keyMap") == "vim"){ 
             //Call handleEsc()
          }
        }
      }
```

But I have no idea, how to make it work. Any help would be very appreciated.

Comment: Why don't you try [the issue tracker](https://github.com/codemirror/codemirror/issues)?

Answer (score 1):

If you return `CodeMirror.Pass` from a key handler, further handlers will be tried. So in this case, simply do that when your condition (being full-screen) does not hold.

`extraKeys: {
  Esc: function(cm) {
    if (cm.getOption("fullScreen")) cm.setOption("fullScreen", false);
    else return CodeMirror.Pass;
  }
}`

Comment: I've added some code -- its a tiny modification of your example `extraKeys` option.

Answer (score 0):

Finally figured a quick way out. I removed the "Esc" key-mapping and used the Codemirror's `keydown` event as following,

```
CodeMirror.on(editor, 'keydown', function(cm,event) {
      if(event.keyCode==27){
        if(editor.getOption("fullScreen"))
          toggleFullScreen();//exit full screen
      }
    });
```

In this way, I didn't have to use the `extraKeys` method and hence vim "Esc" is not overridden and still working.